# Redis : New Keys not persisted in concurrent requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, concurrency, redis

We have integrated Redis cache in our application which is working fine in normal scenarios. Recently we found a very strange issue in our application where newly added keys are automatically removed and modified keys are having old values in case of concurrent ajax requests.
Scenarios is like below :

Ajax Request 1 : 
- Reading data from db, taking approax 5-6 seconds to return
- Triggered on page load (document.ready event)

Ajax Request 2 : 
- Triggered on button click
- Setting values in session
- Completes before Ajax request 1 completed

Ajax Request 3:
- Simply reads the session values 
- Found old values , should have received values set by Ajax request 2

So here sequence is like :

1) Ajax Req 1 triggered and started processing,

2) Ajax Req 2 triggered , sets the values in session (modified existing as well as added a new key)

3) Ajax Req 2 completed

4) Ajax Req 1 completed

5) Ajax Req 3 is triggered, got old values which was with Req 1, should have received value set by Req 2

Initially we thought there must be some code which is overwriting values but no such code found.

I tried to reproduce same case using a sample application and able to see similar case there to. 
Below is the source code:

```
public JsonResult Test1()
        {
            Session["MyTest"] = "Vijay";
            SessionManager.ProposalRequestID = 1;
            SessionManager.VendorID = 2;

            return Json(new { reqID = SessionManager.ProposalRequestID, venID = SessionManager.VendorID, mytest = Session["MyTest"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult Test2()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return Json(new { reqID = SessionManager.ProposalRequestID, venID = SessionManager.VendorID, mytest = Session["MyTest"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult Test3()
        {
            return Json(new { reqID = SessionManager.ProposalRequestID, venID = SessionManager.VendorID, mytest = Session["MyTest"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And UI is like below :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="btn1">Set Session</button>
        <button id="btn2">Heavy Task</button>
        <button id="btn3">Use Session</button>
    </div>
    <div style="color:red;height:500px;overflow-y:auto">
        <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SendTestAjaxCall('@Url.Action("Test2")', "Heave Task");

        $('#btn1').click(function () { SendTestAjaxCall('@Url.Action("Test1")', "Set Session") });
        $('#btn2').click(function () { SendTestAjaxCall('@Url.Action("Test2")', "Heave Task") });
        $('#btn3').click(function () { SendTestAjaxCall('@Url.Action("Test3")', "User Session") });
    });

    function SendTestAjaxCall(URL, message) {
        addToLog("Sending request for  " + message);
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            success: function (result) {
                addToLog("Response from " + message, result);
            }
        });
    }

    function addToLog(message, data) {
        $("#message").html($("#message").html() + '<p>' + message + '</p>');
        if (data) {
            addToLog(JSON.stringify(data), null);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: add async :false in ajax and please tell me the result.

Comment: async: false will work since it will start processing request synchronously, but then it will start showing performance issue which will again a new issue  for me.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, It is not related to Redis , but its something related to an intermediate layer we have in our application, which is managing locking mechanism between requests from same user. We found this based on the fact that Redis always stores in key value pair in it will always update last given value in store, but our custom intermediate layer was always restoring session whenever a request ends, so request ended last will restore its session. 
Sorry for invalid doubt on Redis